# Is the Process class in c# an unmanaged resource?

Tags: c#, idisposable

this.proc - is type of `Process[]`.

Should I write anything in the "Free your own state (unmanaged objects)" block to release `Process[]`?

```cs
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (!_disposed)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            foreach (var i in this.proc)
            {
                i?.Dispose();
            }
        }

        // Free your own state (unmanaged objects).
        // Set large fields to null.
        _disposed = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: When you have unmanaged objects in your class you free them there. Have you created/loaded any unmanaged objects/resources?

Comment: You've already disposed the `Process`es in your code `i?.Dispose();`

Comment: No, the resource class is not an unmanaged resource as the Process class is the managed wrapper of the OS‘ (unmanaged) process handles. So you don’t need to implement the full disposal pattern. Just implement IDisposable.Dispose, and throw away the Dispose(bool) method and the ~Classname finalizer.

Comment: The Process class implements IDisposable, so formally you have to dispose it.  It wraps a handle to the process, that handle needs to be released.  *Practically* you'll see lots of sample code that never disposes it.  Which is okay, the class was written so you only ever really need to do it when you set its EnableRaisingEvents property to true.